# Excel Match two datetime - excluding seconds

Tags: excel, vba

I need to compare 2 datetimes including hh:mm (but not ss) and if same retrieve a value, below is the format I tried.
Both formats are datetime. I tried using index match below but no luck and getting errors, pls guide

```
{=INdex(B1:B5,Match(1,A1:A5=C2),0)}


C
Compare following dates =
26-09-2022 09:16
26-09-2022 09:17
26-09-2022 09:18'

with 
A                           B
26-09-2022 09:16:35         Value1
26-09-2022 09:17:20         Value2
26-09-2022 09:18:12         VAlue3
26-09-2022 09:19:12         VAlue3
26-09-2022 09:20:12         VAlue3
```

Comment: ok, so the nearest answer I can find is @Andrew 's one, but without excel formula, I can mark it as answer if the formula is hard to get..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
Sub GetValues()
    Dim rResultCell As Range
    Dim rValueCell As Range

    For Each rResultCell In Range("C1:C3").Cells
    
        For Each rValueCell In Range("B1:B5").Cells
    
            If Left(rValueCell.Offset(, -1).Value, 16) = rResultCell.Value Then
            
                rResultCell.Offset(, 1) = rValueCell.Value
                
            End If
     
        Next rValueCell
    
    Next rResultCell

End Sub
```

Comment: can we do it as excel formula

Comment: If the dates really are dates, I would consider using DATE plus TIME, but if they are strings, extracting the years/months/days/hours/minutes gets harder. Also, I'm a bit confused because you are comparing 3 values against 5 values. Maybe it's a lack of coffee, so I'll fix that right now and drink some.

Comment: Thanks for reply @Andrew, both columns are datetime, its like I am comparing each datetime (including hh:mm, but not seconds)  in column C to Column A and fetch value from Column B if datetime matches.

Comment: I suspect it's possible, but unfortunately I can't offer a quick solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use `DateDiff`:

```
If DateDiff("n", FirstDateValue, SecondDateValue) = 0 Then
    ' Match.
End If
```

Comment: I need excel formula to fetch the values. also =DATEDIF(C1,A1:A5,"hh:mm") is giving error

Comment: Sorry, I don't do formulas.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `=Int(A1:A5)+Time(Hour(A1:A5),Minute(A1:A5),0)`. The Int part takes care of the date and the Time(hour,minute,0) will remove the seconds from the search.

example of working formula:

```
=XLOOKUP(INT(A15)+TIME(HOUR(A15),MINUTE(A15),0),INT(A$1:A$5)+TIME(HOUR(A$1:A$5),MINUTE(A$1:A$5),0),C$1:C$5,"not found",0,1)
```

[image: note that my system uses ; as formula delimiter]

Comment: I tried ur formula but getting Name error.. as per my requirements this is my formula =XLOOKUP(INT(E3)+TIME(HOUR(E3),MINUTE(E3),0),INT(Di!A$3:A$364)+TIME(HOUR(Di!A$3:A$364),MINUTE(Di!A$3:A$364),0),Di!B$3:B$364,"not found",0,1)   where E3 -->A15, Di!A$3:A$364 --> A$1:A$5 and Di!B$3:B$364 -->C$1:C$5 in your formula.. just asking can I referene the datetime in another worksheet? actually I am getting #Name Error with above forumal, any suggestions

Comment: Seems llike Xlookup only available to office 365, I have ofc 2019 personal edition

Comment: Does your excel sheet allow for a helper column? If so, i would make an extra column that has the second-less datetime and do the lookup on that column instead. I'm not able to test how the array-in-formulas behave in a previous version of excel.

Comment: ok, just want to know, is the syntax: INT(A$1:A$5)+TIME(HOUR(A$1:A$5),MINUTE(A$1:A$5),0) is valid to search on a date range..

Comment: yes, but the way formulas handle arrays is different in the few last versions of excel. This may not work if you don't have the xlookup function. I'm not sure which version started processing arrays...

Answer (score 0):

Having the `Date` in columns A:A and C:C, as seen in your picture, you can use the next formula to match the cells **on the same row**:

```
=IF(ROUND(C2-(A2 - SECOND(A2) * 0.0000115741),6)=0,"Match","")
```

0.0000115741 is the value of a second, in the way Excel keeps time...

Comment: yes @FaneDuru, for the similar row above  forumla is correct, but I need to search in a column to find the matching date and corresponding values